# How to use dropdown list value inside $.getJSON?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax, getjson

this is my script

```
$.getJSON("Employee.js", function (data) { 
       var sample = data.one;alert(sample) });
```

and this is Employee.js file

```
var sample={ "one":"Manager","two":"Sr.Eng","three":"Eng" }
```

I am fine with this. i want to get the value from drop down list. i.e my drop down list will be like follow:

```
 <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlEmployee" runat="server">
                        <asp:ListItem>one</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>two</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>three</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>four</asp:ListItem>
                    </asp:DropDownList>
```

i an get the value of ddlEmployee in jscript as

```
var sel = document.getElementById("<%=ddlEmployee.ClientID%>");
        var opt = sel.options[sel.selectedIndex].text;
```

Bot how to use "opt" to get the value from Employee.js file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use bracket notation:

```
var opt = 'one';

var sample = { "one":"Manager","two":"Sr.Eng","three":"Eng" };

var val = sample[opt]; // Manager
```

Comment: yes. this works fine $.getJSON("Employee.js", function (data) { var sample = data[opt]; alert(sample); })...

Answer (score 0):

Try below code :

```
var data=$.("#ddlEmployee").val();

alert(data);
```

Comment: are you saying like this  var sample = data.$("#ddlEmploee").value;alert(sample)... it will not work.